# DirectoryStream.Filter example for listing files that based on certain date/time

Tags: java, file-io, nio2

I am trying to investigate a `DirecoryStream.Filter` example for `newDirectoryStream` where I can achieve to list all files under a directory(*and all its sub directories*) that are older than 60 days, as an example.

```
DirectoryStream<Path> dirS = Files.newDirectoryStream(Paths.get("C:/myRootDirectory"), <DirectoryStream.filter>);

for (Path entry: dirS) {
    System.out.println(entry.toString());
}
```

In the code above, what should be the `DirectoryStream.filter`? 
It will be a great help as I am in a project where I am trying to delete files older than a certain timestamp and pre-java 1.7 `File.listFiles()` just hangs.

Could `Files.walkFileTree()` provide an option?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I get this right, you have 2 situations:

1. Create a custom `filter` to select files older than 60 days
2. Traverse through subdirectories (the entire `FileTree`) and gather your information

The custom filter is easier to implement with conditions of 60 days implemented using `Calendar` class:

```
DirectoryStream.Filter<Path> filter = new DirectoryStream.Filter<Path>() {
    @Override
    public boolean accept(Path entry) throws IOException {BasicFileAttributes attr = Files.readAttributes(entry,BasicFileAttributes.class);
    FileTime creationTime = attr.creationTime();
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    int days = cal.fieldDifference(new Date(creationTime.toMillis()),Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
        return (Math.abs(days) > 60);
        }
  };
```

The normal execution would only look for the files in the root directory. To look for subdirectory, your guess of using `walkFileTree()` is right.

However, this requires an implementation of the `FileVisitor` interface, a simple implementation of which luckily is bundled with 7 - `SimpleFileVisitor`.

To traverse through the subdirectories, you can choose to override a directory specific method - I have used `preVisitDirectory` of `SimpleFileVisitor` here:

```
Files.walkFileTree(dirs, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
            @Override
            public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path file,
                    BasicFileAttributes attrs) {
```

Since `preVisitDirectory` will be custom made to `return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;` in case you don't have any additional restrictions, we would leverage `preVisitDirectory` method to iterate through our directory 1 at a time while applying the filter.

```
Files.walkFileTree(dirs, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
            @Override
            public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path file,
                    BasicFileAttributes attrs) {

                DirectoryStream.Filter<Path> filter = new DirectoryStream.Filter<Path>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean accept(Path entry) throws IOException {
                        BasicFileAttributes attr = Files.readAttributes(entry,
                                BasicFileAttributes.class);
                        FileTime creationTime = attr.creationTime();
                        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                        int days = cal.fieldDifference(
                                new Date(creationTime.toMillis()),
                                Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
                        return (Math.abs(days) > 60);
                    }
                };
                try (DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(
                        file, filter)) {
                    for (Path path : stream) {
                        System.out.println(path.toString());
                    }
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;

            }
        });
```

This would give you the files from the entire directory and subdirectory structures for the required filter criteria, complete main method below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Path dirs = Paths.get("C:/");

        Files.walkFileTree(dirs, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
            @Override
            public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path file,
                    BasicFileAttributes attrs) {

                DirectoryStream.Filter<Path> filter = new DirectoryStream.Filter<Path>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean accept(Path entry) throws IOException {
                        BasicFileAttributes attr = Files.readAttributes(entry,
                                BasicFileAttributes.class);
                        FileTime creationTime = attr.creationTime();
                        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                        int days = cal.fieldDifference(
                                new Date(creationTime.toMillis()),
                                Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
                        return (Math.abs(days) > 60);
                    }
                };
                try (DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(
                        file, filter)) {
                    for (Path path : stream) {
                        System.out.println(path.toString());
                    }
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;

            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for these details.

Answer (score 4):

Simply create a new `DirectoryStream.Filter` instance that returns `true` if the given `Path` object is older than 60 days.

```
DirectoryStream<Path> dirStream = Files.newDirectoryStream(Paths.get("/some/path"), new Filter<Path>() {
    @Override
    public boolean accept(Path entry) throws IOException {
        FileTime fileTime = Files.getLastModifiedTime(entry);
        long millis = fileTime.to(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
        // L is necessary for the result to correctly be calculated as a long 
        return today.getTimeInMillis() > millis + (60L * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    }
});
```

Note that this will only give you the files inside the root of the specified directory `Path`, ie. the `Path` argument passed to `newDirectoryStream(..)`.

If you want all files in sub directories as well, `Files.walkFileTree(..)` is probably easier to use. You'll just have to implement a `FileVisitor` that stores a `List` or `Set` of `Path` objects that you collect along the way using the same logic as the `Filter` above.