# I want to find if a file exists or not in java

Tags: java

I want to find if a file exists or not in java 
The name of the file can `abc_*_*.xml` (where * represents any character or number)

```java
temp = File.createTempFile(startfilename + "_" + "" + ".xml");
boolean exists = temp.exists();
```

How to check for various combinations of filename where only the start of the file name is similar and the rest of the filename after _ is different

Comment: there can be any text present in place of the underscore(_)

Comment: get a list of all the files present, and check their names against your startfilename

Answer (score 0):

Use the Files api

```
if(!Files.exists(Paths.get("yourpathhere"))){
    /*you code here*/    
}
```

and then you can use this in any cycle you need

as if you want to iterate items in directory, use Files.newDirectoryStream.

[filter example here(stackoverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21733390/directorystream-filter-example-for-listing-files-that-based-on-certain-date-time)

Comment: yes, but that way, you would need to have the actual path. The question is about when you don't have the actual path

Comment: Exactly the problem is i will have the path but the name of the file will be generated through the code only a part of the file name will match with the existing file name so i want to know how to match with only a part of the filename

Comment: then you shold use newDirectoryStream(path,filter) from [Files api](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html)